# Hide "ship to a different address" on WooCommerce checkout page when cart only contains 1 specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm basing this on a previous SO post, but in my case, the "ship to a different address" section disappears no matter what is in the cart.

I have one product that's virtual and when you add that to the cart, and it's in the cart all by itself:

- Ship to area does not appear.
- If any other product is in the cart, including with the other product. the Ship to does appear because you are now shipping a product.

The code I'm using is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 'disable_checkout_shipping_address');
function disable_checkout_shipping_address( $needs_shipping_address ) {
    $products_ids = [3649];
    $found = false;
    $others_found = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
       if (in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), $products_ids ) ){
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $others_found = true;
        }
    }
    if( $found && ! $others_found )
        $needs_shipping_address = true;

    return $needs_shipping_address;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count( WC()->cart->get_cart() )`. If the specific product is in the cart and there is only 1 product in the cart = hide, else = show.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address( $needs_shipping ) {    
    // The targeted product id
    $targeted_id = 3649;

    // Flag
    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( in_array( $targeted_id, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // True & only 1 item in cart
    if ( $found && count( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) <= 1 ) {
        $needs_shipping = false;
    }

    return $needs_shipping;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', 10, 1 );
```